# php code - trying to loop array

Tags: php

I am noticing some strange behavior while looping through some data. I'm sure it's something simple, but I can't seem to be able to find the bug. 
I have the following logic:

```
            <?php
            print 'dumping data : <BR>';
            var_dump($portvlan);
            print '<BR>';
            print 'looping through data: <BR>';
                foreach ($portvlan as $vlandetail){
                    echo 'Vlanid: '.$vlandetail['VlanId'].'<BR>';
                    echo 'Name: '.$vlandetail['Name'].'<BR>';
                    echo 'Mode: '.$vlandetail['Mode'].'<BR>';
                }
            ?>
```

This is the output that I'm getting:

```
dumping data :
array(3) { ["VlanId"]=> string(2) "33" ["Name"]=> string(6) "USR_33" ["Mode"]=> string(6) "Access" }
looping through data:
Vlanid: 3
Name: 3
Mode: 3
Vlanid: U
Name: U
Mode: U
Vlanid: A
Name: A
Mode: A
```

What I was expecting was to see it print a row with 3 cells, with the following values: 
33, USR_33, Access.

Can you tell me where I'm going wrong? 
Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

This logic works fine when the $portvlan array has more than one entry. 
For example, on another set of data, the var_dump gives this result:

```
array(6) { [0]=> array(3) { ["VlanId"]=> string(1) "1" ["Name"]=> string(1) "1" ["Mode"]=> string(5) "Trunk" } [1]=> array(3) { ["VlanId"]=> int(2) ["Name"]=> int(2) ["Mode"]=> string(5) "Trunk" } [2]=> array(3) { ["VlanId"]=> int(3) ["Name"]=> int(3) ["Mode"]=> string(5) "Trunk" } [3]=> array(3) { ["VlanId"]=> int(4) ["Name"]=> int(4) ["Mode"]=> string(5) "Trunk" } [4]=> array(3) { ["VlanId"]=> int(5) ["Name"]=> int(5) ["Mode"]=> string(5) "Trunk" } [5]=> array(3) { ["VlanId"]=> string(2) "33" ["Name"]=> string(2) "33" ["Mode"]=> string(5) "Trunk" } }
```

And the loop logic works fine.

Comment: Are you intending for `$portvlan` to be an array of `vlans`?  If so, then your data should be an array of arrays, i.e., `array(array("VlanID" => "33", "Name" => "USR_33", "Mode" => "Access"))`.  How are you retrieving the source data?

Comment: @mellamokb can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

`$vlandetail` will be populated with a different item from the array on every iteration of the loop. You shouldn't be treating `$vlandetail` as an array. Just use it directly.

To get the key name of the array entry, you have to change the loop structure to this:

```
foreach ($portvlan as $key => $vlandetail) {
     echo $key . ': ' . $vlandetail . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: the code only seems to be failing when i only have one record in the $portvlan.  If I have multiple records, it loops through fine with the current logic.  ?

Comment: Then the problem is probably in the code where you are adding data in the portvlan array.

Answer (score 0):

How you get your `$portvlan`?

If you can know is `$portvlan` is not an array of `$vlandetail`, you can simply do this,

```
$portvlan = array($portvlan);
// start loop
```

Or you can do this before you loop it, to make sure `$portvlan` is a numerical array formed by `$vlandetail`

```
$portvlan = (isset($portvlan[0]))?$portvlan:array($portvlan);
// start loop
```